# Change view depending on click in Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

How can I change the view in my Angular2 template:

```
<td *ngIf="hour === first">{{obj[0].from}}</td>
<td *ngIf="hour === second">{{obj[1].from}}</td>
<td *ngIf="hour === third">{{obj[2].from}}</td>
```

This td is a part of bigger table, but you'll get the logic.

Now I have another part of template below:

```
<div class="info">
     <p>{{schedule[0].name}}</p>
     <p>{{schedule[1].name}}</p>
     <p>{{schedule[2].name}}</p>
</div>
```

I need to match the click on the first `td` so that only first `p` will be displayed in the `.info` class and others will not be visible, and so with the others: if second `td` is clicked, the second `p` should be displayed, other not, etc..

I've tried following this tutorial: http://jilles.me/ng-click-and-ng-if-in-angular2/ but couldn't get it to work. In my actual template there is more stuff besides the p, but I believe the logic should be the same.

How can I do this?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly use ngFor for printing the `p` as follows:

```
<div class="info">
     <p *ngFor="let s of schedule">{{s.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Secondly use index and add the `hidden` tag to the `p` as follows:

```
<div class="info">
     <p *ngFor="let s of schedule; let i = index" 
         [hidden]="hiddenIndex === i">{{s.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Thirdly add `click` method on td which calls a function that sets the `hiddenIndex` value.

```
<td *ngIf="hour === first" (click)="setHiddenIndex(0)">{{obj[0].from}}</td>
<td *ngIf="hour === second" (click)="setHiddenIndex(1)">{{obj[1].from}}</td>
<td *ngIf="hour === third" (click)="setHiddenIndex(2)">{{obj[2].from}}</td>
```

in the class:

```
hiddenIndex: number;

setHiddenIndex(index: number) {
  this.hiddenIndex = index;
}
```

That's it. My solution uses `hidden` instead of `ngIf`. We can't use `ngIf` and `ngFor` on one element so if you'd like to use `ngIf` you need to build your html a bit differently.

Comment: Thanks. Give me a minut please :)

Comment: By the way if you need only one ```p``` be visible at the start, you need to set ```hiddenIndex: number = 0``` in the class (0 for the first p element).

Comment: The issue is with why I was using array indexes is, because with the *ngFor all {{schedule.name}} s get displayed..

Comment: Okay, so you need to print only some of the schedules, right? Back to your previous code then and use my solution in the same way :) Just set the [hidden] manually on each element.

Comment: Give me a second please :)

Comment: Strange, I've appllied your technique. It hides the div I wanted to be displayed, and all others are visible..

Comment: I don't want it to be hidden, but displayed. :)

Comment: You helped, I've used !== instead of === and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh yea, my bad. To make it more logic, change ```hiddenIndex``` to ```shownInden```. Have a nice day.

Comment: I did, visibleIndex :)))

Comment: thinking outside of the box. How would you do it if you would use `i` ?

Comment: There is one thing that you can edit. Instead of having multiple ```p``` just leave only one like: ```<p>{{schedule[visibleIndex].name}}</p>```. Well, I'd create separate array where I'd move all those schedules I'd like to (I'd use filter in ngOnInit) and then use that filtered array with ngFor and index.